# Calculating days to next birthday in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have the date of birth of a person and want to calculate the days until his/her next birthday. How to do this in a way to deal with leapyears and other "odd" things?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that using WolframAlpha for calculating the days is the most "simple" way to do it. Use the following code:

```
REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN("";ImportXML(JOIN("";"http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=birthday+";YEAR(A2);"-";MONTH(A2);"-";DAY(A2);"&asynchronous=false&equal=Submit"); "//script")); "(\d+) days until next")
```

Where `A2` is the cell with the birthday of the person.

Comment: I have been using excel so far to just store a few numbers and strings, with no exposure to such techniques (like the one you just suggested) so far. Could you explain how to actually 'run' this?

Answer (score 8):

Using google spreadsheet internal functions:

```
=IF(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2))>TODAY(),
  DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2)),
  DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+1,MONTH(A2),DAY(A2)))
-TODAY()
```

where *A2* is the cell with the birthday of the person.

The *IF* at the beginning is for testing if the next birthday is this year or next year.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly shorter neater version using pure sheets functions is:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A2)+DATEDIF(A2,TODAY(),"y")+1,MONTH(A2),DAY(A2))-TODAY()
```

This simpler, and uses the `DATEDIF(...,"y")` to get complete years that have passed and adds one, rather than needing an `If` around the entire calculation.

Having figured this out working on the problem myself, I then came across the same solution on [this site](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/days-until-birthday.html), which includes some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

following the nice and short version that [Jon Egerton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592111/jon-egerton) posted, here is a small change that returns 0 when the birthday is on the current day (instead of returning 365), and also handles future dates

```
=DATE(YEAR(A2)+IF(A2<TODAY(),DATEDIF(A2+1,TODAY(),"y")+1,-DATEDIF(TODAY(),A2,"y")),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2))-TODAY()
```